# Database Relation Anomalies

Tags: sql, database, entity, relational-database, relationship

I am tasked to find anomalies within this relation. I had identified a few insertion, deletion and update anomalies.

[image]

`Commission Percentage: the percentage of the total sales made by a salesperson that is paid as commission to that salesperson.`

`Year of Hire: the year the salesperson was first hired`

`Department Number: the number of the department where the salesperson works
Manager Name: name of the manager of the department`

However, I am confused with a anomalies that I pulled out. Below is the statement:

**There can not be a manager with the same name in the company as there is no primary identifier for the manager entity except for the name, which can be a duplicate within the company.**

May I know how should I phrase the above statement and under which (update/deletion/insertion) anomaly should I include it in?

Thank you

---

May I request additional assistance below as well:

2. How would you change the current design and how does your new design address the problems you have identified with the current design.

My current design is splitting it into 3 relations:
`Salesperson(salespersonNumber, salespersonName, commissionPercentage, YearOfHire, deparetmentNumber)`

`Product(productNumber, productName, unitPrice)`

`Manager(managerNumber, managerName, departmentNumber)`

However, I am missing out quantity entity. 
Quantity requires composite key of productNumber & salespersonNumber.
Should I make it in another relation by itself?

`Quantity(productNumber, salespersonNumber)`

Comment: What were the procedures you were given to identify and to address anomolies?  PS: Find a fill-in-the-(named-)blanks statement (*predicate*), where the blanks are named by attributes, that a row of values turns into a statement (*proposition*). Rows for true propostions go in the table & for false stay out. Don't use any pronouns; reuse attributes instead. Then whenever there's an anomaly its because of problematic ANDing of conjuncts. We drop ANDs and make new tables whose predicates are the conjuncts.

Comment: What *definition* were you given for "anomaly"? Because "There can not be a manager..." is maybe a *problem* (informal term), but it's not an *anomaly* (technical term)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Anomalies

When identifying identifying (potential) anomalies, you're listing dependent attributes that are affected by the anomalies (you forgot `Salesperson Name`, btw).  Specifically, you listed attributes that depended on a subset of the key `(Salesperson Number, Product Number)`, thus violating 2NF.  You're on the right track.

However, be careful not to confuse attributes with anomalies.  An update anomaly would be if 1 of the 3 instances of `Bilstein` got changed.  The (assumed) functional dependency `Salesperson Name depends on Salesperson Number` would be broken and the data would be inconsistent (Salesperson Number 437 would be associated with more than one name).  Remember that normalization aims to eliminate redundant **associations**.

2. Identity

The problem with identifying managers by name indicates a poor modeling decision.  As you stated, a company's set of managers isn't uniquely identified by name, so there's a mismatch between the logical data model and the world it models.  This won't cause insert, update or delete anomalies as long as we use different values for different managers, but it will prevent convenient identification of managers.  Possible improvements would be to use multiple attributes (abstract domains are often easily identified by a combination of attributes, but natural domains like people usually aren't, e.g. `Manager Name, Birthdate` would be more identifying but still not a good solution), turn the `Manager Name` into a surrogate key (e.g. `Scott1`, `Scott2`), or introduce a new surrogate key (e.g. a numeric ID).

3. Proposed improvement

Your proposed design normalizes the original table as well as addressing the identification problem.  It's a good answer except for two issues: it doesn't include the association between Salesperson and Manager, and in your `Quantity` relation, you forgot to include the quantity as a dependent attribute.

Good job so far, hope this helps.